# Adding custom attribute to quote item

Tags: magento2, quote, quoteitem

I want to add custom attribute to quote item called item_delete for example. This attribute it's to know if a a item can or can not be deleted from cart.

I've already created an extension_attributes.xml file with the following.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Api/etc/extension_attributes.xsd">
<extension_attributes for="Magento\Quote\Api\Data\CartItemInterface">
    <attribute code="is_delete" type="boolean" />
</extension_attributes>
```

Also i've  a plugin:

```
/**
 * @param \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item\Repository $subject
 * @param \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item $result
 */
public function afterSave(\Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item\Repository $subject, $result){

                $newItem = ObjectManager::getInstance()->get('\Magento\Quote\Api\Data\CartItemInterface');
                $newItem->setQuoteId($cartId);
                $newItem->setQty(1);
                $newItem->setSku($discount);


               $newItem->getExtensionAttributes()->setIsDelete()

}
```

So i want to add "is delete" attribute to quote item  api rest response.

Comment: Did you get any solution for this ?

Comment: Please refer this link for add custom field to quote item using extension attributes. https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/284951/magento-2-add-extension-attributes-in-quote-item

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing out the interface and its concrete class. Please take a look at this

https://store.fooman.co.nz/blog/an-introduction-to-extension-attributes.html