# Magento 2 Add extension attributes in Quote Item

Tags: magento2, api, magento2.2.2, quoteitem, extension-attributes

I want to add custom attribute in quote items Magento\Quote\Api\Data\CartItemExtensionInterface

```
<extension_attributes for="Magento\Quote\Api\Data\CartItemExtensionInterface">
    <attribute code="cust_price" type="float" />
</extension_attributes>
```

I did this doesn't know how to proceed further.
Dont know which plugin i have to use to accept and set attribute data
I have run API for add item

**POST** : `rest/V1/carts/mine/items?cart_id=27333`

```
{
"cartItem": 
    {
        "sku": "SCC010010000",
        "qty": 1,
        "price": 15,
        "quote_id": "27333",
        "extension_attributes": {
            "cust_price" : 25
        }
    }
}
```

And error is `Property \"CustPrice\" does not have corresponding setter in class \"Magento\\Quote\\Api\\Data\\CartItemExtensionInterface\".`

Comment: use plugin at api level when product adding to cart.

Comment: which method and which type name i have to override?

Comment: Plugin is not meant to override the file, it meant for update object while some action. Please read about magento plugin from https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html

Comment: yes i know that but dont know which <type name="{ObservedType}"> and methods i have to change

Comment: will you be specific by answer>

Comment: you need to save that extension attribute in quote table

Comment: What are the steps you have done so far?

Comment: I want to set cust_price as item price when item is beeing added to cart i have did above steps only

Answer (score -1):

The following approach works fine for me to add the custom attribute or field to the quote item using the extension attribute in Magento 2.

Step 1: Create module.xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Company_CustomModule" setup_version="1.0.2">
    </module>
</config>
```

Step 2: Create extension_attributes.xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Api/etc/extension_attributes.xsd">
<extension_attributes for="Magento\Quote\Api\Data\CartItemInterface">
    <attribute code="bambuseritem_flag" type="string" />
</extension_attributes>
</config>
```

Step 3: Create di.xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item\Repository" type="Company\CustomModule\Model\Quote\Item\Repository" />
</config>
```

Step 4: Create UpgradeSchema.php file.

```
<?php

namespace Company\CustomModule\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeSchemaInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table;

class UpgradeSchema implements UpgradeSchemaInterface
{
    public function upgrade(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $installer = $setup;
        $installer->startSetup();
        $setup->startSetup();
        if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.0.2', '<')) {
            $tableName = 'quote_item';
            if ($installer->getConnection()->isTableExists($tableName) ) {
                $installer->getConnection()->addColumn(
                    $installer->getTable($tableName),
                    'custom_flag',
                    [
                        'type' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                        'length' => 10,
                        'nullable' => true,
                        'comment' => 'Custom Flag'
                    ]
                );
            }
        }
        $setup->endSetup();
    }
}
```

Step 5: Send custom flag filed in add to cart REST API payload Or Request for Guest & Register user are as below.

```
{
    "cart_item": {
        "quote_id": "75d1a5424a279581a34b9a1b4f4df020",
        "product_type": "configurable",
        "sku": "214480140",
        "qty": 1,
        "product_option": {
            "extension_attributes": {
                "configurable_item_options": [
                    {
                        "option_id": "93",
                        "option_value": "676"
                    },
                    {
                        "option_id": "188",
                        "option_value": "888"
                    },
                    {
                        "option_id": "189",
                        "option_value": "912"
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        "extension_attributes": {
            "custom_flag": "Your Custom Value"
        }
    }
}
```

Step 6: Finally save custom flag filed in quote item using extension attribute.

```
<?php
/**
 *
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Company\CustomModule\Model\Quote\Item;

use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\CouldNotSaveException;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException;

class Repository extends \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item\Repository
{
    /**
     * Quote repository.
     *
     * @var \Magento\Quote\Api\CartRepositoryInterface
     */
    protected $quoteRepository;

    /**
     * Product repository.
     *
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface
     */
    protected $productRepository;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\CartItemInterfaceFactory
     */
    protected $itemDataFactory;

    /**
     * @var CartItemProcessorInterface[]
     */
    protected $cartItemProcessors;

    /**
     * @var CartItemOptionsProcessor
     */
    private $cartItemOptionsProcessor;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Quote\Api\CartRepositoryInterface $quoteRepository
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository
     * @param \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\CartItemInterfaceFactory $itemDataFactory
     * @param CartItemProcessorInterface[] $cartItemProcessors
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Quote\Api\CartRepositoryInterface $quoteRepository,
        \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository,
        \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\CartItemInterfaceFactory $itemDataFactory,
        array $cartItemProcessors = []
    ) {
        $this->quoteRepository = $quoteRepository;
        $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
        $this->itemDataFactory = $itemDataFactory;
        $this->cartItemProcessors = $cartItemProcessors;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function save(\Magento\Quote\Api\Data\CartItemInterface $cartItem)
    {
        /** @var \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote $quote */
        $cartId = $cartItem->getQuoteId();
        $quote = $this->quoteRepository->getActive($cartId);
        $quoteItems = $quote->getItems();
        $quoteItems[] = $cartItem;
        $quote->setItems($quoteItems);
        $this->quoteRepository->save($quote);
        $quote->collectTotals();
        $extensionAttributes = $cartItem->getExtensionAttributes();
        if(null !== $extensionAttributes && null !== $extensionAttributes->getCustomFlag())             
        {
            $itemq = $quote->getItemById($quote->getLastAddedItem()->getItemId());
            $itemq->setCustomFlag($cartItem->getExtensionAttributes()->getCustomFlag());
            $itemq->save();
        }             
        return $quote->getLastAddedItem(); 
    }    
}
```

Comment: I want to save during go to checkout button. How can i proceed for it ?

Comment: Hey, I have provided detailed answers with the API Request body as well. Can you explain whether you are using Rest API?

Comment: I am trying to use during go to checkoout from shopping cart page to checkout

Comment: You need to use the Plugin or Event. Event example for your case is controller_action_predispatch_checkout_index_index for more details refer to this link. https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/138355/magento-2-check-condition-on-click-of-proceed-to-checkout

Comment: I have added custom value to each and every item by select option. now i want to save the save in quote_item table during go to checkout.

Comment: You can check full code in above answer step 6. for quick reference you can get the custom extension attribute or filed value by using $cartItem->getExtensionAttributes()->getCustomFlag() & then set that value.

Comment: You must pass the value from the frontend side, probably from js to the PHP event file then you can refer above step. EX : https://meetanshi.com/blog/use-payment-extension-attributes-in-magento-2/